# L'exception "blanchiment"

Tags: vocabulaire, suffixes

Le mot "blanchiment" m'a toujours paru bizarre et faisant figure d'exception. Il me donne l'impression que "on devrait dire blanchissement" (qui existe aussi avec un sens légèrement différent). Je m'interroge sur cette "exception", étant donné que les verbes du 2ème groupe donnent généralement des noms en *-issement* et pas en *-iment*.

La terminaison en *-issement* est selon moi naturelle car le "*-iss-*" est caractéristique du 2ème groupe. Pour cette même raison je ne suis pas surpris de sa relative absence dans les noms formés sur des verbes 3ème groupe.

Est-ce vraiment une exception ? On a bien le mot "bâtiment" par exemple. En cherchant une liste exhaustive, je me suis rendu compte que le nombre d'exemples est quand même très réduit. Les seuls que j'ai trouvés sont :

> blanchiment, bâtiment, boniment, assortiment (et dérivés), et fourniment (doublet de fourniture assez rare)

On a aussi les dérivés de sentiment que je mets à part, notamment car sentir est un verbe du 3e groupe :

> assentiment, ressentiment, dissentiment, pressentiment

On peut également noter "châtiment" qui est le seul déverbal d'un verbe du 1er groupe à avoir une terminaison en *-iment*. Enfin, on a aussi le mot "régiment", qui ne vient pas vraiment du mot "régir" mais directement du latin *regimentum*, qui lui vient bien de *regere*, "régir".

À part ces exemples, tous les noms en *-ment* formés sur des verbes du deuxième groupe finissent en *-issement*, et non en *-iment*.

> barrissement, rétrécissement, assoupissement, enfouissement, lotissement, retentissement, ...

Si on ne le considère par comme une exception à l'échelle de tous les noms déverbaux, au minimum c'est une exception parmi ceux liés aux couleurs :

> noircissement, jaunissement, bleuissement, verdissement, ...

---

Est-ce que "blanchiment" est à considérer comme une exception (au sens large) ?

D'où vient cette construction irrégulière ?

Comment: Autres "exceptions" : sentiment, ressentiment, assortiment.

Comment: @Graffito je les ai mentionnés dans la question :)

Comment: Bah oui, je ne devais pas être bien reveillé :(

Comment: Je ne dirais pas que c'est une exception, c'est un autre mot que blanchissement - voisin dans le sens et l'ethymologie - mais ancien aussi et qui aujourd'hui revêt un caractère essentiellement financier et est même défini dans la loi française https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/section_lc/LEGITEXT000006070719/LEGISCTA000006149840

Comment: Tu avais consulté la [BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/22421/le-vocabulaire/paronymes/sens-et-emploi-de-blanchiment-blanchissement-et-blanchissage) ? Et le [BtB](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/juridi/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_b&page=9gTpGMaOUcGs.html) ?

Comment: @None Je sais que blanchiment et blanchissement existent et ont des sens différents, ce n'est pas sur ça que porte ma question. Ça n'explique pas pourquoi il est irrégulier dans sa forme. Le fait que les deux existent pose même plus de questions qu'il n'apporte de réponses. On n'a pas "noirciment" et "noircissement", pourquoi on a "blanchiment" et "blanchissement" ?

Comment: @None Pour répondre littéralement, non je n'avais pas consulté ces ressources, mais elles n'apportent pas de réponse à ma question.

Answer (score 3):

Il semble que ces exceptions soient issues de l'influence des substantifs en -iment dérivés de verbes du troisième groupe, eux-mêmes transformés depuis -ement.

> Sous l'infl. de ces mots, des dér. en -iment ont été créés à partir de verbes en -ir: assortiment, blanchiment, pressentiment. On trouvait en a. fr.: amortiment, baniment, enchériment (cf. Nyrop t. 3 1936, § 412).

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ment

Comment: La suite est aussi très intéressante : "*Blanchiment pourrait aussi venir de l'ancien français "blanchier" avec amuïssement de -e-.*"

Comment: Oui, l'entrée "blanchiment" du TLfi précise qu'il est soit dérivé de blanchir (source Nyrop) soit de blanchier (source Alexis) mais dont il ne reste que 2 attestations.

Answer (score 0):

> Je ne dirais pas que c'est une exception, c'est un autre mot que
> blanchissement - voisin dans le sens et l'etymologie - mais ancien
> aussi et qui aujourd'hui revêt un caractère essentiellement financier
> et est même défini dans la loi française
> https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/section_lc/LEGITEXT000006070719/LEGISCTA000006149840
> ([Simon Mourier](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53562/lexception-blanchiment#comment113984_53562), en commentaire sous licence [CC BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing))